# How to convert Evernote API Timestamps to Postgresql Timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, evernote

I'm accessing the Evernote API via the evernote gem for ruby on rails, and I'm storing the objects (notebooks, tags, notes, etc.) in a Postgresql database.

Evernote returns timestamps that look like this:

- 1344141917000
- 1344141967000
- 1344138641000

The [evernote api documentation](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Types.html#Typedef_Timestamp) says this is the number of milliseconds that have passed since the base time of January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

I've conducted the following exercise in the rails console in an attempt to reconstruct the date.

```
evernote_timestamp_base = Time.gm(1970,01,01,00,00,00)
=> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC 
evernote_timestamp_base + 1344138641000
=> 44564-01-22 04:43:20 UTC
```

Definitely not right. But chopping those last three zeros off yields the right date:

```
evernote_timestamp_base + 1344138641
=> 2012-08-05 03:50:41 UTC
```

Am I missing something here? What's the deal with those last three zeros? Will I have to parse and chop the evernote timstamp values and then add them to the 1970 base, or is there an easier way?

Also, what's the best Postgresql data type for storing these values?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this in Ruby, use Time.at. You'll need to divide by 1000 since Evernote timestamps are in millseconds and Ruby/Unix timestamps are in seconds.

```
createdNote = noteStore.createNote(authToken, note)
createTime = Time.at(createdNote.created / 1000);
puts "Note was created at #{createTime}"
```

Comment: This more closely answered my question, and arrived at the solution without need for an evernote_timestamp_base variable. Thanks @Seth.

Answer (score 5):

In postgresql you could use a timestamp [with|without] time zone as the type for the column.

The unix timestamp is defined as the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT which is what Ruby and many other systems use and or support. PostgreSQL can do the conversion for you to. Just pass the value in seconds to the to_timestamp function.

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1344138641000/1000.0)
```

To convert it back use

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM col)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me realize I can treat this value as a number (dividing by 1000), instead of text (which I'd have to parse). This makes the solution a bit easier.